# Switch to different sanity project

Tags: command-line, sanity

I have multiple sanity projects in my account. How can I switch to a particular account/project in my sanity cli for deploying the schema to correct project ?

Comment: What commands are you using? Usually the CLI is run in the folder of the sanity project. If you want a different project, why not try and change the folder?

Comment: Yes, I using it in folder of sanity project. It seems currently sanity CLI does not provide a way to deploy to particular project id.

Answer (score 0):

Currently sanity CLI does not provide a direct way to deploy schema to particular projectID. But it can be done in to ways:

- Type `sanity init` in your sanity project and then select your project
  id.
- Just change the projectID in sanity.json.

Comment: Why would it? Sanity projects are contained within different folders? I'm a little confused why you'd need this? Would you explain?

Comment: I was just replicating a sanity project. Just wanted to deploy to another account with same content.

Comment: @evolutionxbox perhaps if you were creating a whitelabel site for another client, different "project" same source code.

Comment: @jfgilmore a solution could be to copy white-label template, and run the commands from that folder?